# Equal symbol in the title

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a script that displays the file name in the title, but when it contains the equal symbol "=" in the beginning the title is not displaying the symbol

```
For /F "delims=" %%t in ("%~n0") do (Title %%~t)
```

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly well for me.

Comment: I put a sample image

Comment: Still works fine for me. Perhaps it's brand new (for your convenience) in Windows 10?

Comment: I tested this code in Windows XP, 7 and 10 and got the same "error".

Comment: @HumbertoFreitas, I am not understanding the example.  Are you saying your batch file name starts with an "=" symbol?

Comment: I get the `=` symbol; with a non-initial `=`, I get that displayed correctly. Win7

Comment: @Squashman It seems so, but the general question could be, how to get a equal sign or comma at the front of a title (after the first character it isn't a problem anymore)